# PHP MySql: print total post monthly archive

Tags: php, mysql

I need to print Total(count) news archive by month of year(12 month) in json format like this :

Output:

```
["January:31","February:28","March:0","April:130","May:450","June:0","July:0","August:0","September:0","October:520","November:20","December:31"]
```

PHP Code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS id,
YEAR(date) as `year`,
MONTH(date) as `month`,
MONTHNAME(date) as `month_name`,
FROM `aticle`
GROUP BY `year`, `month`;
```

**NOTE:** `if we dont have news in any month print:0` **i.e**: `"March:0","July:0".....`

How do can i print this?!

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: StackOverflow is to be used as a *guide* to get you to the answer, we will *not* write the code for you. What have you written so far in an attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(<column_containing_news_count>) AS num_of_articles,
MONTHNAME(date) as month_name
FROM aticle
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date);` ?

Comment: @esqew: This True. But I dont Have any idea for this. my problem is this!

Comment: @user27133 You could start by executing the query and loading the results into an array, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating a row for each month/year combination that you want.  Assuming that you have at least one value for each month and year, the easiest way is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS id, y.yr, m.mon, m.mname
FROM (select distinct year(date) as yr from article) y cross join
     (select distinct month(date) as mon, monthname(date) as mname from article) m left join
     article a
     on year(a.date) = y.yr and month(a.date) = m.mon
GROUP BY y.yr, m.mon;
```

Otherwise, you will have to find a way to get a list of all months, using something like:

```
select 1 as mon, 'Jan' as mname union all
. . .
```

Comment: The easiest way Not Work.You Test this?

Comment: @user27133 . . . I have run similar queries many times.  How does it not work?

Comment: i add this Code for output: `$value = array(); foreach($stats as $key => $value){
   $rows2[] = $value['mname'];
   }
 echo json_encode($rows2);` output is : `[null,"February",null,"February"]` this is simple for print all month.

Comment: For print i choose true way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL` for check if data not found it should be `0`..

Please try query given below.

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS id, YEAR(date) as `year`, MONTH(date) as `month`, MONTHNAME(date) as `month_name`,FROM `aticle`GROUP BY `year`, `month`;
```

thanks